# How to make this generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have got a question. How to make this whole code generic? So the variables, methods and classes? If somebody can show how this have to be done. It would help me a lot!

```
public class Linkedlist { 
     private Node head; 

     private class node{ 
        Object data; 
        Node next;
        }

      //Getter for data head-node
      Object getFirstDate () {
```

Thanks!

Comment: Get some [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) on generics for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you wish to make your class `Node` generic. In this case add generic definition and change type of `data` from `Object` to `T`:

```
private class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more or less like that:

```
public class Linkedlist<T> { 
     private Node<T> head; 

     private class Node<T>{ 
        T data; 
        Node next;
        }

      //Getter for data head-node
T getFirstDate () {
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple generic example try to analyze the example i gave after [reading this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) 
You will automaticaly get your answer

```
class A<T>
{
    T value;
    public A(T x)
    {
        value=x;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
class GenericType{
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        A<String> x=new A("It is a String class");
        A<Integer> y=new A(5);
        x.display();
        y.display();
    }
}
```